# How to display balloon counter over application launcher icon?

Tags: notifications, launcher

Is there a way display a "balloon counter" notification on top of an application launcher icon (like iOS)?

[image: screen shot of a sample notification]

Comment: Well, that would really only apply to apps that have a "message count" (or similar) to even display. Have you looked at the iPhone-esque launchers already in the Play Store?

Comment: Also, we really prefer questions that ask about a problem to be solved rather than an app to be found.

Comment: sounds like problem to me, you can still flag it

Comment: I tweaked the language to make it a question about a problem to be solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Go Launcher EX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.golauncherex.notification) looks like you can turn that on, at least for some apps.

Related is the [Next Notification](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gtp.nextlauncher.notification) plugin for Next Launcher 3D.